# Consume only new ElasticSearch documents using NiFi

Tags: elasticsearch, etl, apache-nifi

I have a use case where I have to periodically fetch new records using NiFi (only records not fetched before) for a particular index and pipe it to other storage doing some ETL.

I'm not sure how to handle fetching only new records. Did anyone handle use cases like that?

Answer (score 0):

can you be more specific about **fetching only new records**?
when you say, **only records not fetched before**, does that mean with a specific timeline? 
what records are being termed as new records? Is there any time-specific requirement?